# FFMPEG compiling on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ffmpeg, carrierwave

I have a Rails app running in heroku.

I wanna watermark an original AUDIO-file with another AUDIO-file through a merging/mixing (amerge or amix) filter. Also fades and looping should work.

FFMPEG must be compiled for this feature to run on heroku.
My steps I got from this GIST which uses [Vuclan](https://github.com/heroku/vulcan)

https://gist.github.com/liufengyun/5055354

Locally I use the following term to convert with [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) which is an uploader:

```
"-i Original.aiff -i public/watermark/#{ENV['WATERMARK_FILENAME']}.aiff -loop 1 -filter_complex '[1]afade=t=in:ss=0:d=1[4];[4]afade=t=out:st=#{self.evaluate_length-2}:d=2[5];[5][0]amix=duration=shortest[out]' -map [out]"
```

This works with the ffmpeg built in on my mac.

My compiled version for heroku does contain amerge, amix and the libavformat library.

This is the log which I got from heroku when I go to my upload form and uplaod a file:
(all this works, but only locally).

```
Started POST "/sounds" for 84.113.97.32 at 2013-07-15 21:14:33 +0000
2013-07-15T21:14:33.175631+00:00 app[web.1]: Running transcoding...
2013-07-15T21:14:33.175631+00:00 app[web.1]: ffmpeg -y -i /tmp/sounds/1373922873-2-5714/watermark_loop-95.aiff -i public/watermark/1khz.aiff -loop 1 -filter_complex '[1]afade=t=in:ss=0:d=1[4];[4]afade=t=out:st=-2.0:d=2[5];[5][0]amix=duration=shortest[out]' -map [out] /tmp/sounds/1373922873-2-5714/watermark_loop-95.aiff
2013-07-15T21:14:33.175631+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-15T21:14:33.241221+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed encoding...
2013-07-15T21:14:33.241221+00:00 app[web.1]: ffmpeg -y -i /tmp/sounds/1373922873-2-5714/watermark_loop-95.aiff -i public/watermark/1khz.aiff -loop 1 -filter_complex '[1]afade=t=in:ss=0:d=1[4];[4]afade=t=out:st=-2.0:d=2[5];[5][0]amix=duration=shortest[out]' -map [out] /tmp/sounds/1373922873-2-5714/watermark_loop-95.aiff
2013-07-15T21:14:33.241221+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-15T21:14:33.241221+00:00 app[web.1]: ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavformat.so.54: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2013-07-15T21:14:33.241221+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-15T21:14:33.241221+00:00 app[web.1]: Errors: encoded file is invalid.
2013-07-15T21:14:33.241221+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-15T21:14:33.277487+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-15T21:14:33.277487+00:00 app[web.1]: FFMPEG::Error (Failed encoding.Errors: encoded file is invalid. Full output: ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavformat.so.54: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2013-07-15T21:14:33.277487+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-07-15T21:14:33.277487+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/uploaders/sound_uploader.rb:39:in `watermarking'
2013-07-15T21:14:33.277487+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

It's my 6th attempt to compile, get ffmpeg running correctly and watermarking my sounds on heroku.

Please help me out of this neverending story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forgotten to add all subpaths to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

So I changed my heroku variable from

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: vendor/ffmpeg/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

to

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: vendor/x264/lib:vendor/mp3lame/lib:vendor/ffmpeg/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

via

```
 heroku config:set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=vendor/x264/lib:vendor/mp3lame/lib:vendor/ffmpeg/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

I have made a gist with detailed compiling instructions for FFMPEG on HEROKU

https://gist.github.com/klangfeld/6009744